# JavaNullPointerexception problema en Array

Tags: java, array

mi problema es que tengo:

> 'JavaNullPointerException' in 'kits[k] =
>   plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString(b);'

Tengo este código,

```
        int numberKits = 2;
        int n = 1;
        int k = 0;
        int m = 1;

        //Bucle for para imprimir en el chat el nombre de todos los kits de propertiesKits.yml
        for(int i=1; i <= numberKits; i++){
            String a = "Kits.kit"+n+".name";
            sender.sendMessage(plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString(a));
            //Aqui acab de imprimir los nombres de los kits

            //Bucle for que almacena en el array kits el nombre de todos los kits de propertiesKits.yml

            for(int j=1; j <= numberKits; j++){
                String b = "Kits.kit"+m+".name";
                kits[k] = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString(b);
                sender.sendMessage(kits[k]);
                m++;
            }
            //Aqui acaba el for de kits
            n++;
        }
```

Comment: Debes de traducir tu pregunta a español, esto es stackoverflow en español amigo, si no te la van a cerrar.

Comment: array 'kits' not exist

Comment: No veo declarado en ningún lado el arreglo kits

Comment: debes agregar tu clase plugin para saber exactamente el problema creo que te falta más información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es un problema común

```
'JavaNullPointerException' in 'kits[k] = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString(b);'
```

se puede ocasionar por varias causas

- el arreglo `kits` no esta inicializado.
- `plugin` es null   el método
- `.getPropertiesKit()` obtiene un valor
  null.

debes agregar más información por ejemplo tu clase `plugin` y verificar declarar e inicializar el array `kits[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Analizando tu código hay tantas cosas que pueden estar provocando el problema, quizá debas colocar todas las piezas para poder ayudarte mejor. Te menciono algunas de las que veo.

Suponiendo que todo esta inicializado de manera correcta. El problema estaría en la inicialización de tus variables de recorrido `i` y `j`, recordar que en Java el primer elemento de un array está en la posición 0 no en la posición 1 y que el último elemento está en la posición `n - 1` no en la posición `n`. Para tu código siempre estarías dejando sin evaluar el primer elemento del array e intentando evaluar un elemento más del que tienes en el array.

En tu código siempre reescribes el valor de `kits[k]` porque `k` siempre es 0, no lo aumentas; y estamos suponiendo que `kits` ha sido correctamente inicializado.

Coloca tu `stackTrace` para tener un mejor panorama del problema, si es que ninguno de los puntos expuestos solventa tu problema.